# What is this doing: "var timer = duration, minutes, seconds"?

Tags: javascript, timer

Trying to make a timer and came across this:

```
function timer(duration){
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);...
```

I've never seen a variable defined like this.

`minutes` and `seconds` are defined in setInterval callback, how is `timer` getting these?

Moreover, how can `timer` be more than one thing? There's something I'm missing here.

Original [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wr1ua0db/17/)

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: declares three vars, timer, minutes, seconds, and initialises timer = duration

Comment: Equivalent to `var timer = interval; var minutes; var duration;`